# Rails activeadmin Export PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, wicked-pdf

I'm helping a friend with a ruby on rails site. I'm really new at ruby on rails and the developer that developed the site is long.

The app uses the activeadmin gem and currently there is a column in the documents section that supposedly exports the document in PDF format but is not working. Here is the code. From app/admin/documents.rb

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Document do

  index do
    column :id
    # This was buggy
    column :user_name do |d|
      d.user.nil? ? 'No User' : (link_to d.user.name, admin_user_path(d.user))
    end
    column :user_email do |d|
      d.user.nil? ? 'No User' : d.user.email
    end
    column :price do |document|
      document.price.nil? ? 'Gratis' : document.price
    end
    column :type_document
    column :status
    column :download do |document|
      link_to 'Download PDF', document_path(document, format: :pdf)
    end
    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Edicion" do
      f.semantic_errors
      f.input :content
      f.input :price
      f.input :status, as: :select, collection: Document::STATUSES
      f.actions
    end
  end

  csv do
    column :user_name
    column :user_email
    column :price
    column('Tipo') { |document| document.type_document }
    column :status
    column(:content) { |document| strip_tags(document.content) }
  end

end
```

I Installed the wicked_pdf gem, but I'm stuck here. I do not know how to proceed. I found this code to generate the PDF

```
def generate_pdf(document)
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      document.content,
      encoding: 'UTF-8',
      page_size: 'A4',
      orientation: 'Portrait',
      template: 'documents/documento.pdf.rb',
      margin:  {    top:               30,                     # default 10 (mm)
                    bottom:            30,
                    left:              20,
                    right:             20
      },
      layout: 'layouts/pdf.html'
    )
    send_data(
      pdf,
      filename: "document_#{document.type_document}_#{document.user.name}.pdf",
      disposition: 'attachment'
    )
  end
```

I'm not sure if that code is correct and also how can I link the Download PDF link to this function?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Carlos Sosa

Comment: you can add a button on using active admin action items https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html#action-items then call the generate_pdf method from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure how to call the method from the column: download and also where to define the method.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the download PDF link here:

```
link_to 'Download PDF', document_path(document, format: :pdf)
```

The `generate_pdf` method contents could be added to, or called from, that controller endpoint.

Assuming you already have a `DocumentsController#show` action, it could look something like this:

```
def show
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # render existing view
    format.pdf do
      generate_pdf(@document)
    end
  end
end

private

def generate_pdf(document)
  # same content you posted
end
```